# How to separate radio buttons?

Tags: html, css

I'm aware this may seem like a stupid question that every should know. But I just can't for the life of me work it out.

The look I need to achieve is:

| == radio button

|Terrorists *nice even spacing here* |Counter-Terrorists

I have these radio buttons:

[Image](http://gyazo.com/9b67f923ddfc95c871f4d3e6057445c0)

But what i need is for them to be equally spaced while staying in the dead center of the page.

Ive messed around with them for ages to no avail.

HTML:

```
   <input type='radio' id='choice' value='terrorist' class='radiopick'>Terrorist's
   <input type='radio' id='choice' value='countert' class='radiopick'>Counter-Terrorist's
```

CSS:

```
input.radiopick{

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean evenly spaced?  Could you illustrate with, for lack of a better program, illustrator?

Comment: sorry i don't get which look you want to achieve. can you clearify this...

Comment: @Axel The look i want will now be added to the post

Comment: Sorry @TaylorStevens its still not clear to me!!! BTW: Your "radios" don't have a unique id-attribute which is very bad practice. Another question do you want a multiple choice (i suggest: nope). Why don't you wrap your text into label tags? Is it possible that you are completely new to html. Don't get me wrong - i don't want to be unpolied but help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

**HTML**

```
<form>
<div class="radiopick">
    <input type='radio' id='choice' value='terrorist' />Terrorist's</div>
<div class="radiopick">
    <input type='radio' id='choice' value='countert' />Counter-Terrorist's</div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form {
display:flex;
text-align:center;
}
form .radiopick {
justify-content: center;
width:150px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what i need, I just need the spacing to be a bit smaller! How would i make it smaller? Ive messed around with the width etc wont make it smaller.

Comment: You need to change the margin in the css.  For example make it 80%.  Also, be careful as this CSS will make ALL forms like this.  I would recommend calling the form something (like <form id="y">) and then changing the css from form to it (for the "y" example change the form to .y).

Comment: adjust the width and that's it. You can also see more about the flex property at http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: btw @PopeyGilbert , while you're correct in identifying the form, this won't affect the input of any other form unless he adds an additional div named radiopick. Also, he NEEDS to keep the margins as I added, not 80%, it's part of the solution that makes the flex behaves like this

Comment: Just incase people have an annoying tendency of skim-reading questions, my second reply is wrong :).  +1 to Fabio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using tables?  Although I don't fully understand the question, if you want even spacing for each box you could do something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:300px" align="center">
<tr>
  <td><input class="radiopick" type="radio" name="test" value="yes" />Terrorist</td>
  <td><input class="radiopick" type="radio" name="test" value="yes" />Counter-Terrorist</td>        
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

An example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t5r75rvw/)